# Book with a school for teenage vampires who can't go out during the day or they'll burn; and heroine falls in love with the teacher

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire

I have read this book in high school, there were vampires, and other half-breeds or something, and they cannot go out until they're turned out to be full-fledged vampires. I think they were called fledglings? And this main character (teenage girl) falls in love with her teacher?

And they have tattoo-like natural markings on their body, I think those were white ones. And then there were dead vampires coming to life, with red markings? I don't remember much but there were so many books.

Aphrodite was the name of one character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *House of Night* series by P.C. Cast, starting with *Marked* (2007), 12 books total.

Summary from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30183.Marked#bookDetails):

> After **a Vampire Tracker Marks her with a crescent moon on her forehead**, 16-year-old **Zoey Redbird enters the House of Night and learns that she is no average fledgling.** She has been Marked as special by the vampyre Goddess Nyx and has affinities for all five elements: Air, Fire Water, Earth and Spirit. But she is not the only fledgling at the House of Night with special powers. When she discovers that the leader of the Dark Daughters, the school’s most elite club, is mis-using her Goddess-given gifts, Zoey must look deep within herself for the courage to embrace her destiny – with a little help from her new vampyre friends (or **Nerd Herd, as Aphrodite calls them**)

---

Found with the Google query `scifi book vampires school "aphrodite" site:goodreads.com/book`.

Comment: Thank you!! Thats it!